# Checkout to another existing branch with changes from develop

Tags: git, version-control, branch, rebase

I have a simple scenario.

So, I have 3 branches

- **develop**
- **feature_1**
- **feature_2**

I have changed something on /feature_1 committed and merge it to develop

And now I want to change something in the feature_2 branch, but it's not up to date, develop is a few commits ahead. I want that feature_2 branch is a copy from the develop branch.

I want to do something like this

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

but to exsiting branch, I don't want to create a new branch.

So what should I do, because I've read a lot about it and should I checkout to feature_2 and pull from develop?

rebase?

merge?

please give me the best solution

Comment: It is not really clear to me what a branch named `navbar` and `footer` are supposed to do. It does not make much sense to create separate branches for a navbar, or a footer of a webpage.

Comment: it's just an example of names ;) it could be everything

Comment: For example develop, feature1, feature2 

feature1 is merged to develop 

feature2 is a place where I want to change something but I want to have all changes from develop here

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem After branch name clarification, would you mind trying to answer this question? I'm curious too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the command **`git pull origin develop --rebase`** on `feature_2` branch will get what you needed.

Assume the commit history for now as below:

```
      E-----F-----G     feature_1
     /             \
…---A---…---B---C---D   develop
             \
              H---I     feature_2
```

After executing `git pull origin develop --rebase` on `feature_2` branch, the commit history will be:

```
      E-----F-----G     feature_1
     /             \
…---A---…---B---C---D   develop
                     \
                      H'---I'    feature_2
```

As you find, `feature_2` branch will on the latest commit `D` from `develop` branch.

---

Besides, if you haven’t committed changes on `feature_2` branch (no commit `H` and `I` on `feature_2` branch) as below graph:

```
      E-----F-----G     feature_1
     /             \
…---A---…---B---C---D   develop
            |
        feature_2
```

Except the way `git pull origin develop --rebase`, you can use below commands to reset `feature_2` branch on the top of `develop` branch:

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -B feature_2
```

**Note:** `-B` option for `git checkout` command will create a new branch if the branch name not exist. While if the branch name exist, it will reset the existing branch.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where **feature_2** is unaffected by the changes made on **develop** then I would just finish **feature_2** and then merge with **develop**.

In the case where **feature_2** needs the changes made on **develop**, then if **feature_2** has not been published (your the only person working on it) then I would rebase it on **develop**, because it creates a cleaner history. If you're not the only one working on **feature_2**, then I would merge **develop** into **feature_2**, such that the other people that work **feature_2** don't get their history changed.